# Make solid circles that interact with each other in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, physics

I am making a small game with basic physics and I can't figure out how to make circles interact with each other, and with rectangles. All I want is to make a solid object in the game. I can't use a engine or library, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you see the [tutorials on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265053(v=vs.85).aspx)?  In particular, the [Detecting collisions in a 2D HTML5 game](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265052(v=vs.85).aspx) seems relevant to your interests.

In particular, here's the code used to detect collisions in that tutorial:

```
var circlesOverlap = function(circleA, circleB) { // Public. Returns true if the SVG circles A and B overlap, false otherwise.
  var deltaX = circleA.cx.baseVal.value - circleB.cx.baseVal.value;
  var deltaY = circleA.cy.baseVal.value - circleB.cy.baseVal.value;
  var distance = Math.sqrt( (deltaX*deltaX) + (deltaY*deltaY) ); // The classic distance-between-two-points formula.
  var radiusA = circleA.r.baseVal.value; // The radius of circle A.
  var radiusB = circleB.r.baseVal.value; // The radius of circle B.

  if (circleA.id == circleB.id) // If true, circleA and circleB are the same circle.
    return false;

  return distance <= (radiusA + radiusB);
}; // circlesOverlap()

that.circlesOverlap = circlesOverlap;
```

Note that the technique used in the tutorial is basically:

- Track each object
- Calculate the distance between the objects
- Respond accordingly (e.g. when the distance is zero).

(Update: added the sample that seems most relevant to your question, per the comments below)

Do take time to read the full tutorial, though, for the full context and to ensure that due credit is duly credited.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Seems more a comment than an answer?

Comment: Is it?  Sorry.  Still learning the unwritten rules.  Is there a FAQ of such things?  I looked but didn't find one.

Comment: Generally, link-only answers are discouraged because the post will spoil if the link goes bad: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. So by default link-only posts are better put in the comments. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Note that other sites encourage people use reputable research sources and to respect/credit authorship.  I'll grant that content on MSDN has occasionally gone missing, but I do know that the content I pointed to is also available on archive.org (https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265052(v=vs.85).aspx, in case you need help finding it.)

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to save each circle's x and y coordinates, x and y velocity (in pixels), as well as radius.  keep a list of all of your circles.  On each iteration of your animation loop, check that each circle's x and y coordinates plus or minus the radius are not on top of one another if the circles advance the number of pixels noted by their x and y velocities. If they are, handle what you want them to do (i.e. change direction, stop, etc.) and then redraw.